# Jenkins 2.304: Failed to monitor for Free Swap Space

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins 2.304, Java 11.

When launching a job to a remote machine, observed a Free Swap Space failure. What could cause it?

```
Remoting version: 4.10
This is a Unix agent
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by jenkins.slaves.StandardOutputSwapper$ChannelSwapper to constructor java.io.FileDescriptor(int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of jenkins.slaves.StandardOutputSwapper$ChannelSwapper
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Evacuated stdout
ERROR: Failed to monitor for Architecture
ERROR: Failed to monitor for Free Disk Space
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to monitor for Clock Difference
Failed to monitor for Free Swap Space
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at hudson.remoting.Request$1.get(Request.java:321)
at hudson.remoting.Request$1.get(Request.java:240)
at hudson.remoting.FutureAdapter.get(FutureAdapter.java:65)
at         hudson.node_monitors.AbstractAsyncNodeMonitorDescriptor.monitorDetailed(AbstractAsyncNodeMonitorDescriptor.java:113)
at     hudson.node_monitors.AbstractAsyncNodeMonitorDescriptor.monitor(AbstractAsyncNodeMonitorDescriptor.java:77)
at hudson.node_monitors.AbstractNodeMonitorDescriptor$Record.run(AbstractNodeMonitorDescriptor.java:305)
```

Comment: Suggest logging a [Jenkins issue -JIRA](https://issues.jenkins.io/projects/JENKINS/issues). Also, try doing as it says: "Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release."